# 'Resource exhausted' memory error when trying to train a Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to train a VGG19 model for a binary image classification problem. My dataset doesn't fit into the memory, so I use batches and the `.fit_generator` function of the `model`.

However, even when trying to train with batches, I get the following error:

> W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of
>   memory trying to allocate 392.00MiB.  See logs for memory state.
>
> W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Resource exhausted: OOM
>   when allocating tensor with shape

Here's the console output about my GPU when starting the training script:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Found 20000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 5000 images belonging to 2 classes.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 750M
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.085
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 1.95GiB
Free memory: 1.74GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 750M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
```

I don't know, but I think 1.5+ GB should be enough to train on small batches, right?

The full output of the script is quite huge and I'll paste a piece of it to [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dtCLZSR0).

Below is the code for my model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

class VGG19(object):
    def __init__(self, weights_path=None, train_folder='data/train', validation_folder='data/val'):
        self.weights_path = weights_path
        self.model = self._init_model()

        if weights_path:
            self.model.load_weights(weights_path)
        else:
            self.datagen = self._datagen()
            self.train_folder = train_folder
            self.validation_folder = validation_folder
            self.model.compile(
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy']
            )

    def fit(self, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10):

        train_generator = self.datagen.flow_from_directory(
                self.train_folder, target_size=(224, 224),
                color_mode='rgb', class_mode='binary',
                batch_size=2
        )

        validation_generator = self.datagen.flow_from_directory(
            self.validation_folder, target_size=(224, 224),
            color_mode='rgb', class_mode='binary',
            batch_size=2
        )

        self.model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            samples_per_epoch=16,
            nb_epoch=1,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            callbacks=[
                TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_images=True),
                ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_loss'),
                ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
            ],
            nb_val_samples=8
        )
    def evaluate(self, X, y, batch_size=32):
        return self.model.evaluate(
            X, y,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            verbose=1
        )

    def predict(self, X, batch_size=4, verbose=1):
        return self.model.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    def predict_proba(self, X, batch_size=4, verbose=1):
        return self.model.predict_proba(X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    def _init_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

        return model

    def _datagen(self):
        return ImageDataGenerator(
            featurewise_center=True,
            samplewise_center=False,
            featurewise_std_normalization=True,
            samplewise_std_normalization=False,
            zca_whitening=False,
            rotation_range=20,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            vertical_flip=True
        )
```

I run the model the following way:

```
vgg19 = VGG19(train_folder='data/train/train', validation_folder='data/val/val')
vgg19.fit(nb_epoch=1)
```

and my `data/train/train` and `data/val/val` folders consist of two directories each: `cats` and `dogs`, so that `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` function could separate my classes correctly.

---

What am I doing wrong here? Is it just that VGG19 is too big for my machine or it's some problem with batch sizes?

What can I do to train the model on my machine?

---

PS: if I don't interrput the training script (even though it outputs lots of similar errors like one in the pastebin above), the last lines of the output are the following:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] *****************************************************************************************xxxxxxxxxxx
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 392.00MiB.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 6, in <module>
    vgg19.fit(nb_epoch=1)
  File "/home/denis/WEB/DeepLearning/CatsVsDogs/model/vgg19.py", line 84, in fit
    nb_val_samples=8
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 907, in fit_generator
    pickle_safe=pickle_safe)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1378, in fit_generator
    callbacks._set_model(callback_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 32, in _set_model
    callback._set_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 493, in _set_model
    self.sess = KTF.get_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 111, in get_session
    _initialize_variables()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 200, in _initialize_variables
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_variables))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4096]
     [[Node: Variable_43/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_43"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Variable_43, Const_59)]]

Caused by op u'Variable_43/Assign', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 6, in <module>
    vgg19.fit(nb_epoch=1)
  File "/home/denis/WEB/DeepLearning/CatsVsDogs/model/vgg19.py", line 84, in fit
    nb_val_samples=8
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 907, in fit_generator
    pickle_safe=pickle_safe)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1351, in fit_generator
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 696, in _make_train_function
    self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 387, in get_updates
    ms = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 278, in zeros
    dtype, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 182, in variable
    v = tf.Variable(value, dtype=_convert_string_dtype(dtype), name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 224, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 360, in _init_from_args
    validate_shape=validate_shape).op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4096]
     [[Node: Variable_43/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_43"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Variable_43, Const_59)]]
```

---

### Update 1

Following @rmeertens's advice, I've made last Dense layers smaller:

last block:

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

and the error changed a bit. It's still an OOM error though: [pastebin.com/SamkUbJA](http://%20pastebin.com/SamkUbJA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the OOM error appears because your graph is too large. What is the shape of the tensor you tried to allocate when everything goes down?

Anyway, a first thing you could try is allocating the model without having any of data in memory. Is something else still running (another jupyter notebook, some other model service in the background).

Also, maybe you can save space in the last layers:

```
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

A 4096x4096 matrix is pretty big (and immediately going back to 1 is a bad idea anyway ;) )

Comment: Following your advice, I've changed first Dense to the size 1024 and the second Dense to the size 256 and it started to give a bit different output. It actually starts to run the training, but still I get the OOM error, but in a different way, here's the error I get: http://pastebin.com/SamkUbJA  Could you help me to find out what else is wrong in my code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the VGG16 model from the top of my head, and I don't know what kind of application you are training, but: maybe it is a good idea to cut down on half of your layers... Make the model less deep, use bigger strides, smaller input, more maxpool layers, anything to use less memory. Gradually expand your network if it is not learning wel..

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your help! I'll tick your post as an answer, 'cause you did help me to deal with my issue and pointed to the right direction.

Comment: The VGG model is suited for lots of different classes. If you're trying to find only a few classes, you can probably reduce the model a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you tell me that this model is working i'd be very surprised.

Having a softmax activation on 1 output (your last layer) doesnt make sense. 
The softmax normalizes the outputs of a layer so that they sum up to 1... if you only have one output it will be 1 all the time! So if you want a binary probability, either use sigmoid on 1 output or use softmax on 2 outputs!

Comment: Yep, that's a good point. I've already tried using softmax on 2 outputs with categorical_crossentropy loss and sigmoid with 1 output and binary loss. Anyways, I ended up using a much smaller model, 'cause my laptop cannot handle a larger one. With my tiny model I get only 80% accuracy on a validation set

Comment: Are you using tf backend? If yes, tf is known to be very greedy in memory on gpu... so indeed consider reducing the size of your network :-) it is currently huge... and will probablu take weeks to train on a small GPU like that

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'm using tensorflow backend. I'm quite new to deep learning, so I'm kinda just trying things out and testing my machine's capabilities. Thanks to helpful answers I get here, on SO, I'll learn things much faster. Thank you again for your advice)